# Converting a Sprite into Bitmap using Wiengine in android

Tags: android, game-engine

I am working in game development using Wiengine for android phones.
I want to convert a sprite into bitmap.
Can any one let me know how can I achieve this functionality.
I am getting the sprite from Zwoptex sheet and I want to setTexture using that sprite.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct api can do this but you can make a screenshot to catch the sprite rect. However, why do you need this feature?